# Pasar texto de formato plano a columnas en bash

Tags: bash

Tengo que dar formato a un archivo de texto plano `.log`/`.txt` en columnas.

La información sale de una consulta SQL, por lo tanto puede variar en cuanto a filas, pero con el mismo patrón.

Estoy realizando un script bash para tratar el archivo.

Actualmente lo tengo tal que así:

```
whiletest.sh

contador=0
while read -r line ;
do
#       echo "${line:0:4}"
        if [ ${line:0:4}  == "TIME" ]; then
                echo  "${line} <-"
                contador=$[contador +1]

        else
                echo "${line}"
        fi
done < whiletest.log
echo $contador
```

Al ejecutar el código anterior me imprime la siguiente salida:

```
TIME         |CAJAS_HORAS_M4 <-
-------------|--------------
08/09/2021 02|           419
08/09/2021 01|          1008
08/09/2021 00|          1861
07/09/2021 23|          1488
07/09/2021 22|          1102
07/09/2021 21|           623
07/09/2021 20|          1965
07/09/2021 19|          1160
TIME         |CAJAS_HORAS_M3 <-
-------------|--------------
08/09/2021 03|           381
08/09/2021 02|           768
08/09/2021 01|           773
08/09/2021 00|           920
07/09/2021 23|           844
07/09/2021 22|          1011
07/09/2021 21|           418
07/09/2021 20|           741
07/09/2021 19|           632
TIME         |CAJAS_HORAS_M2 <-
-------------|--------------
08/09/2021 04|           315
08/09/2021 03|           997
08/09/2021 02|           825
08/09/2021 01|           779
08/09/2021 00|           513
07/09/2021 23|           957
07/09/2021 22|           865
07/09/2021 21|           422
07/09/2021 20|           515
07/09/2021 19|           317
TIME         |CAJAS_HORAS_M1 <-
-------------|--------------
08/09/2021 03|           719
08/09/2021 02|          1035
08/09/2021 01|          1031
08/09/2021 00|           581
07/09/2021 23|           841
07/09/2021 22|           763
07/09/2021 21|           392
07/09/2021 20|           314
07/09/2021 19|           733
4
```

La idea es que quede así:

```
TIME         |CAJAS_HORAS_M4  TIME         |CAJAS_HORAS_M3  TIME         |CAJAS_HORAS_M2
-------------|--------------  -------------|--------------  -------------|--------------
08/09/2021 02|           419  08/09/2021 03|           381  08/09/2021 03|           997
08/09/2021 01|          1008  08/09/2021 02|           768  08/09/2021 03|           997
08/09/2021 00|          1861  08/09/2021 01|           773  .......
07/09/2021 23|          1488  08/09/2021 00|           920
07/09/2021 22|          1102  07/09/2021 23|           844
07/09/2021 21|           623  07/09/2021 22|          1011
07/09/2021 20|          1965  07/09/2021 21|           418
07/09/2021 19|          1160  07/09/2021 20|           741
                              07/09/2021 19|           632
```

Y así con todas las columnas.

He intentado realizar `printf`, `awk` y no he conseguido formatearlas correctamente.

Tampoco sé si realizando las consultas SQL ya se puede ordenar correctamente en columnas.

Comment: ¿Puedes modificar la consulta SQL? Agrega el código.

Comment: ¿Los símbolos `<-` los has agregado tú manualmente o están en el archivo?

Comment: @OscarGarcia fijate en la parte del for existe un if que hace eso: `echo  "${line} <-"` asi que el codigo de el lo hace.

Comment: Tratare de editar la pregunta ya que dice 'El archivo "whiletest.log" me saca lo siguiente:' cuando realmente debería decir 'Al ejecutar el código anterior me saca lo siguiente:'

Comment: Lo entendí al ver tu código. Ya te he redactado una respuesta

Comment: @OscarGarcia no es mi código .-.

Comment: Disculpa @AgileSoul, no me fijé que no eras el autor.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Prueba el comando column:

```
column -t -s','
```

Esto es lo que puedo conseguir rápidamente. Consulte la página del manual para obtener más detalles.

Comment: No me ayudó mucho esto, alguna aportación más?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
# Ruta donde guardaremos el archivo dividido
TEMPORAL="$(dirname "$0")/temporal"

# Creamos o limpiamos el directorio temporal
if [ -d "$TEMPORAL" ]
then
        find "$TEMPORAL" -type f -delete
else
        mkdir "temporal"
fi

# Patrón que tendrán los archivos generados
PATRON="${TEMPORAL}/%05d.parte"

# Llevamos la cuenta de las partes para generar el nombre del archivo
contador=0
longitud=0
# Esta es la longitud máxima (en líneas) de los archivos
LONGITUD_MAX=0
# Este será el ancho máximo que tendrán las columnas
ANCHO=0
while read -r linea
do
        if [[ $linea =~ ^TIME ]]
        then
                ((contador += 1))
                # Calculamos si hemos superado el número de líneas
                if [ $longitud -gt $LONGITUD_MAX ]
                then
                        LONGITUD_MAX=$longitud
                fi
                # Restablecemos la longitud y el nombre del archivo
                longitud=0
                ARCHIVO=$(printf $PATRON $contador)
        fi
        ((longitud += 1))
        echo "$linea" >> "$ARCHIVO"
        # Calculamos la longitud máxima de una línea
        if [ ${#linea} -gt $ANCHO ]
        then
                ANCHO=${#linea}
        fi
done < whiletest.log

# Si las columnas no tienen la misma anchura habrá que igualarlas
# (sin hacer porque por ahora son iguales)

# Igualamos la longitud en líneas de los archivos
find "$TEMPORAL" -type f | while read -r archivo
do
        # Obtenemos el número de líneas del archivo
        NUM=$(wc -l < "$archivo")
        # Por cada línea de menos agregamos una línea con relleno
        for i in $(seq $((NUM+1)) $LONGITUD_MAX)
        do
                printf "%${ANCHO}s\n" "" >> "$archivo"
        done
done

# Usamos "pr" para mezclar los archivos en columnas
pr -tTmJ -i2000 -e2000 temporal/* | \
        # Agregamos un espacio como separador en vez de un tabulador
        sed "s/\t/ /g"
```

Resultado:

```
TIME         |CAJAS_HORAS_M4 TIME         |CAJAS_HORAS_M3 TIME         |CAJAS_HORAS_M2 TIME         |CAJAS_HORAS_M1
-------------|-------------- -------------|-------------- -------------|-------------- -------------|--------------
08/09/2021 02|           419 08/09/2021 03|           381 08/09/2021 04|           315 08/09/2021 03|           719
08/09/2021 01|          1008 08/09/2021 02|           768 08/09/2021 03|           997 08/09/2021 02|          1035
08/09/2021 00|          1861 08/09/2021 01|           773 08/09/2021 02|           825 08/09/2021 01|          1031
07/09/2021 23|          1488 08/09/2021 00|           920 08/09/2021 01|           779 08/09/2021 00|           581
07/09/2021 22|          1102 07/09/2021 23|           844 08/09/2021 00|           513 07/09/2021 23|           841
07/09/2021 21|           623 07/09/2021 22|          1011 07/09/2021 23|           957 07/09/2021 22|           763
07/09/2021 20|          1965 07/09/2021 21|           418 07/09/2021 22|           865 07/09/2021 21|           392
07/09/2021 19|          1160 07/09/2021 20|           741 07/09/2021 21|           422 07/09/2021 20|           314
                             07/09/2021 19|           632 07/09/2021 20|           515 07/09/2021 19|           733
                                                          07/09/2021 19|           317
```

El parámetro de `tr` que realiza el trabajo es `-m, --merge`:

> `-m, --merge`
>
> print all files in parallel, one in each column, truncate lines, but join lines of full length with `-J`

En castellano:

> `-m, --merge`
>
> imprime todas los archivos en paralelo, uno en cada columna, trunca las líneas, pero une las líneas con su ancho completo usando `-J`