# ¿Cómo obtengo el basename, path y número de ocurrencias de una string en un directorio y subdirectorios?

Tags: linux, script, shell

Tengo que crear un script de Linux que tome un directorio, una cadena con una lista de palabras y un archivo de salida como parámetros. De cada palabra en la cadena, tengo que mostrar el basename y la ruta de cada archivo y el número de apariciones de esa palabra en el archivo. Esto debe mostrarse en tres columnas con tabuladores como espacios entre cada elemento, así:

*basename_file path_file number_of_occurences*

De momento he realizado esto:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$1 

STRING=$2

FILEOUT=$3

for item in $STRING

do

    BASE=$( basename -a $(grep -rl $item $DIR) )

    PATHS=$( grep -rc $item $DIR | tr ":" " " )

    echo "$BASE $PATHS" >> $FILEOUT) 
done
```

Al correr este script y hacer `cat` al archivo output "texto.txt"

```
./busca.sh ./Documentos "string file" texto.txt
cat texto.txt
```

He obtenido este resultado:

```
find.txt
grep.txt
sort.txt ./Documentos/find.txt  5
./Documentos/grep.txt   22
./Documentos/sort.txt   1
./Documentos/cut.txt    0
find.txt
grep.txt
sort.txt
cut.txt ./Documentos/find.txt   224
./Documentos/grep.txt   67
./Documentos/sort.txt   7
./Documentos/cut.txt    1
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que cada grupo aparezca alineado, es decir que aparezcan en la misma línea el basename path y número de ocurrencias de cada archivo?

Además, si en la string pongo una palabra que no está presente en ningún archivo basename, me da un error.

Comment: parece que el problema se reduce a poner formato a las columnas, ¿no? Tipo lo visto en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/482952/pasar-texto-de-formato-plano-a-columnas-en-bash